# Getting the attachments of an .msg file in SAPUI5

Tags: email, sapui5, attachment, sap-fiori

I am currently building a Fiori APP with SAPUI5 to upload files. For this I use the UploadSet provided by SAP, where I can drag in files and then upload them. Now I would like to have the ability to drag in an email file (`.msg`) and it will show me the attachments as well as the mail. However, since I don't know how to get to the attachments in the SAPUI5 environment, I need your help.

Is there any way to get to these attachments?

It should look like this:
[Fiori App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKPQB.png)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What did you try so far? What do you mean with get to the attachments? Is this instand upload?

Comment: I have so far built an app that uses the SAPUI5 UploadSet to accept files via drag and drop. These files are then displayed in a list where you can select the ones you want to upload. The selected files are then uploaded by pressing a button.
Now I want that if you drag an email file (.msg) into the list, its attachments are also displayed in the list next to the mail file.
I have added an example screenshot in the post. (Fiori App)

Comment: .msg is an outlook file format. there is no official JS implementation to open this stuff up. You can give this a try https://github.com/ykarpovich/msg.reader, but there is no guaranty  that it works with future outlooks.
I don't think there is a ABAP class to parse those files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BenediktKromer
Can you explain me how to include such library in SAP Fiori application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467187/importing-jspdf-to-sap-business-application-studio/69478150#69478150